# I'm trying creating a pandas dataframe column based on a given condition(multiple condition)

Tags: python, pandas

I used two different codes to solve this:
1. I used if conditions inside the dataframe.
2. I tried to use the functions.

I'm getting the `syntaxerror: invalid syntax`.

I'm still a beginner using Pyton.

1st Method:

```
<df['hours_week'] = ['less_than_40' if x < 40 'between_40_and_45' elif x > 40 and x <= 45 'between_40_and_60' elif x >45 and x <= 60 'between_60_and_80' elif x >60 and x <=80 else 'more_than_80' for x in df['hours_per_week']]>
```

2nd Method:

```
<def set_value(x):
     for x in df['hours_per_week']:
         if x < 40:
             t == print " less_than_40"
         elif (x > 40 and x <= 45):
             t == print "between_40_and_45"
         elif(x>45 and x <=60):
             t == print "between_40_and_45"
         elif(x>60 and x <= 80):
             t == print "between_60_and_80"
         else:
             t == print "more_than_80"
         return t
df['hours_week'] = df['hours_per_week'].apply(set_value,args=())
```

This is what T'm getting with 1st Method:

```
 File "<ipython-input-36-e90a4b2f98cc>", line 1
    df['hours_week'] = ['less_than_40' if x < 40 'between_40_and_45' elif x > 40 and x <= 45 'between_40_and_60' elif x >45 and x <= 60 'between_60_and_80' elif x >60 and x <=80 else 'more_than_80' for x in df['hours_per_week']]
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with 2nd Method:

```
 File "<ipython-input-44-0a5dc69b4a15>", line 4
    t == print " less_than_40"
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` we usually using `pd.cut`

```
df['hours_week']=pd.cut(df['hours_per_week'],bins=[-np.inf,40,45,60,80,np.inf])
```

you can also add labels here , `labels=['less_than_40','between_40_and_45'....]`

Comment: it works, but with a warning message: "
C:..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  after removing the cwd from sys.path."

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
bins = pd.Series([40, 45, 60, 80])

labels = ['less_than_40', 'between_40_and_45', 'between_45_and_60', 
          'between_60_and_80', 'more_than_80']

df['hours_week'] = df['hours_per_week'].map(lambda x: labels[bins.searchsorted(x)])
```

The first label should actually be 'less_than_or_equal_to_40'.

Comment: Thanks @ seanswe! but it still doesn't work. This time, i'm getting a typeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce that error on my end. Can you try making labels a pd.Series? `labels = pd.Series(['less_than_40', 'between_40_and_45', 'between_45_and_60', 
          'between_60_and_80', 'more_than_80'])`

Comment: it works by making a pd.Series for labels. But it includes the indices and dtype of the labels in the created column "hours_week". Thanks